# SQL Select Non-Duplicates From One Column

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm newish to SQL and I'm a little stuck. I'm trying to write a SQL that will get all the finishes that are applied to a wheel. Each wheel has many finishes and each finish has many images at difference angles.

```
This is my code:
    SELECT DISTINCT
    wi.intFinishID,
    wi.blnDefaultFinish
FROM tbl_wheelimage wi
WHERE wi.intwheelID = 4950
ORDER BY wi.blnDefaultFinish DESC
```

The problem that I'm having is that for the default finish it is outputting 2 recods(see below): the default and the non-default. I only need the default.

```
intFinishID       blnDefaultFinish
  10                1
  10                0
  1658              0
```

I'm using SQL Server 2008

Thank you

PS:

The result I'm trying to get is:

```
intFinishID       blnDefaultFinish
  10                1
  1658              0
```

Comment: `WHERE wi.intwheelID = 4950 AND wi.blnDefaultFinish = 0`? (Or `1`, I didn't quite get it)

Comment: please share the table structure. There should be some field (ideally), which will indicate if the record indicates default finish or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    wi.intFinishID,
    MAX(convert(tinyint, wi.blnDefaultFinish)) blnDefaultFinish
FROM tbl_wheelimage wi
WHERE wi.intwheelID = 4950
group by intFinishID
```

You can't use MAX() on bit fields, so I converted it to a tinyint first.

Here's another option:

```
SELECT distinct
    wi.intFinishID,
    case when exists(select * from tbl_wheelimage t where t.intWheelID = wi.intWheelId and t.intFinishID = wi.intFinishID and blnDefaultFinish = 1) then 1 else 0 end blnDefaultFinish
FROM tbl_wheelimage wi
WHERE wi.intwheelID = 4950
```

Another option:

```
select intFinishId, blnDefaultFinish
from
(SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by wi.intFinishId order by wi.intFinishId asc, wi.blnDefaultFinish desc) rowNum,
    wi.intFinishID,
    wi.blnDefaultFinish
FROM tbl_wheelimage wi
WHERE wi.intwheelID = 4950) x
where x.rowNum = 1
```

The first and third options will probably perform the best if you have a large number of records.

Answer (score -1):

Change your WHERE condition to filter your results.

Assuming when "wi.blnDefaultFinish = 1" that means default, where "0" means Non-default.

Therefore, you query should say:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    wi.intFinishID,
    wi.blnDefaultFinish
FROM tbl_wheelimage wi
WHERE (wi.intwheelID = 4950 AND wi.blnDefaultFinish = 1) OR (wi.intFinishID = 1658 AND wi.blnDefaultFinish = 0)             
ORDER BY wi.blnDefaultFinish DESC
```

Comment: With OR wi.blnDefaultFinish = 1 I end up with every default finish in the database, for thousands of wheels

Comment: New answer will get the results you want, but that is only if your dataset does not change. Without knowing the structure of the tables, I can't tell if the code should actually be `WHERE (wi.intwheelID = 4950 AND wi.blnDefaultFinish = 1) OR (wi.intwheelID = 4950 AND wi.intFinishID = 1658 AND wi.blnDefaultFinish = 0)`

Comment: Unfortunately, the dataset changes each time.

Comment: Maybe if WHERE WHERE (wi.intwheelID = 4950 AND wi.blnDefaultFinish = 1) OR (wi.intwheelID = 4950 AND wi.blnDefaultFinish = 0 AND  <nested select>)

Comment: a nested select in the Where clause isn't the right place, but Jerrad's second option looks like it will work.